# Tempered Glass Requirement - Bathrooms

Tags: bathroom, safety, glass, wet

I'm aware that based on the 2018 Residential Code tempered glass is required around wet surfaces (i.e. bathrooms).
However, could someone tell me ***when*** this tempered glass requirement went into effect?

THANKS!

Comment: Did your jurisdiction adopt the change? I know with Oregon they normally adopt the code changes for the building codes division ~ 10 months after the code is released.

Comment: I have had to use tempered glass for showers for 20+ years.   It doesn't have to be an international code for a city to enforce it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to have changed in the 2012 IRC when the requirement for hot tubs was also applied to bathrooms and wet areas

Here is information that references the change and a screenshot is provided below.

[Significant Changes to the International Building Code, 2012 Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=-TX7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT449&lpg=PT449&dq=change%20IRC%20tempered%20glass%20is%20required%20around%20wet%20surfaces&source) via Google Books

[image]

Comment: Ack,Thank you for your GREAT answer!  It is exactly what I was looking for.  I tried to find the exact info in your link but I'm not sure if it is user error, PC error, or an error on the site but I could not open it.  Could you provide (copy/paste) the info here?  GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!!

Comment: Awesome. I think that the issue was my link, I've edited my answer to include a screenshot of the paragraph and updated my link so that it should now work. It links to Google Books review pages. Note that I found this answer via searching and out of a desire to help and learn; I am not at all an expert in this area of the code and this might not be fully what you are after, and if not it should still get you much closer to your desired information / answer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again!